# IntelliJ -- how to highlight modified files that are under version control

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

My IntelliJ by default shows the modified files in blue and the unmodified files in black. It's not very sharp contrast so it slightly annoys me.

Where do I configure the appearance? I want to further highlight the modified files under the version control.

[UPDATE]

I found it following the answer, but many features were grayed out... why is that?

[image]

Comment: They are grayed out because you need to save-as the current theme first, as they are read-only.

Comment: @RyanJ no, I already saved as my own theme. plus the "Foreground" is not grayed out.

Comment: @RyanJ They are [greyed out for me aswell](http://i.imgur.com/q6HI0yh.png), even though I'm using a scheme that's already modified.

Comment: Well that might mean some of those attributes cannot be customized...

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> File Status`, here you can customize the appearance of file names depending on their statuses. See [File Status Highlights](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-status-highlights.html) in the IntelliJ documentation for more information.

Comment: I've just upgraded to IDEA 14 U from IDEA 13 CE and [now the options are avaiable to me](http://imgur.com/cbxV68r.png). But since you tagged this intellij-14 I don't really know if it's gonna help since someone with Ultimate reported it didn't work for them either. Just figured I'd let you know anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Partially covered in the answer by @Marv:

> Go to Preferences -> Editor -> Colors & Conts -> File Status, here you can customize the appearance of file names depending on their statuses.

You can also set the background in `Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviour -> File Colors` if you want more emphasis.

Comment: I don't have [those options](http://i.imgur.com/qLPwWny.png), might this be lacking in the Community Version?

Comment: I have the Ultimate version and those specific options aren't there for me either.

Comment: I have the Ultimate version also - that's how I found the preferences.